# Making Autofac return different classes that implement same interface based on some parameter?

Tags: c#, autofac, factory

Sorry if this was answered before, but I searched and I didn't quite find what I was looking for and I'm not sure if it's because it's a bad practice or because I don't know the appropriate name for what I'm looking.

I have a situation like this: I have a mailing service that uses a different provider depending on which one the client wants. The client may want to send the mail through UPS, DHL, FedEx or USPost. Each of them will implement IMailing

```
public interface IMailing
{
    void Mail(string message);
}

public class UPS : IMailing 
{
    public void Mail(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + ", mailed with UPS!");
    }
}

public class DHL : IMailing 
{
    public void Mail(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message + ", mailed with DHL!");
    }
}

...
```

I want to get each specific implementation of IMailing according to some paramenter. Say, a string, that I would pass to Autofac, that will return an instance of UPS, DHL, FedEx, etc, according to that string key.

Is there anyway to do this? Is it OK?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a named or keyed service. See [Named and Keyed Services](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

Registration

```
builder.RegisterType<UPS>().Named<IMailing>("ups");
builder.RegisterType<DHL>().Named<IMailing>("dhl");
```

Retrieval

```
var r = lifeTimeScope.ResolveNamed<IMailing>("dhl");
```

Alternatively you can inject a lookup based on the name or key into your using type instead of injecting `ILifeTimeScope`.